# Increase view count when each product is opened in React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, json-server

**What i want is to increase the count of each product, when it is opened(viewed), using react redux.**

**AllProductsPage.js(The page starts here)**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ProductList from "./ProductList";
import Pagination from './Pagination'
import * as productActions from "../redux/actions/productActions";
import * as userActions from '../redux/actions/userActions'
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import {FiSearch} from 'react-icons/fi'
import { Container, Row, Col} from "react-bootstrap";

const AllProductsPage =(props)=> {

    const [quantity, showQuantity] = useState(true);
    const [price, showPrice] = useState(true);
    const [manufacturer,showManufacturer] = useState(true);
    const data = {quantity,price,manufacturer};
    const [search,setSearch]=useState("");
    const loggedIn = props.loggedIn;
   
    //Pagination Logic
    const [currentPage,setCurrentPage] = useState(1)
    const postsPerPage = 9
    const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage;
    const currentPosts = props.products.slice(indexOfFirstPost,indexOfLastPost)

    //Change the page
    const paginate =(pageNumber)=>{
      setCurrentPage(pageNumber)
    }


     //const filteredSearch = props.products && props.products.filter(product=>product.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase())!==-1).sort( (a,b)=>(a.id>b.id)?1:-1 );
    const filteredSearch = currentPosts && currentPosts.filter(product=>product.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase())!==-1).sort( (a,b)=>(a.id>b.id)?1:-1 );

    return (
      <div>

        <div style={{"display":"flex","paddingTop":"30px"}} className="container">
         { loggedIn && <Link to="/addProduct"><Button variant="primary">Add Product</Button>{" "}</Link> }

          <span style={{"marginLeft":"auto"}}><input type="text" onChange={event=>setSearch(event.target.value)}/> {" "} <FiSearch size="20px"/> </span>
        </div>

        <div style={{"display":"flex","justifyContent":"flex-end","alignItems":"space-between","paddingTop":"6px"}} className="container" >
          <label style={{"padding":"0px 5px 0px 2px","color":"white"}}><input type="checkbox"  defaultChecked={quantity} onClick={()=>showQuantity(!quantity)}/>{" "}Quantity</label>
          <label style={{"padding":"0px 5px 0px 2px","color":"white"}}><input type="checkbox"  defaultChecked={price} onClick={()=>showPrice(!price)}/>{" "}Price </label>
          <label style={{"padding":"0px 5px 0px 2px","color":"white"}}><input type="checkbox"  defaultChecked={manufacturer} onClick={()=>showManufacturer(!manufacturer)}/>{" "}Manufacturer </label>
        </div>
        
        <hr></hr>

        <div style={{minHeight:"100vh"}}>
        <ProductList 
          products={filteredSearch} 
          data={data} 
          togglePrice={showPrice}
          toggleQuantity={showQuantity}
          toggleManufacturer={showManufacturer}
          loggedIn={props.loggedIn}
        />
        <br />
        <Container>
          <Row>
          <Col></Col>
          <Col xs="auto" sm="auto" md="auto" lg="auto">
            <Pagination postsPerPage={postsPerPage} totalPosts={props.products.length} paginate={paginate} />
          </Col>
          <Col></Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
        </div>
        <footer>
          <p style={{"textAlign":"center","backgroundColor":"#333","color":"white","padding":"20px"}}>Copyright @2020, Rohit K F</p>
        </footer>
      </div>
    );
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    products: state.products,
    users : state.users
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(productActions, dispatch),
    userAction : bindActionCreators(userActions,dispatch)
  };
}
export default (connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps))(AllProductsPage);
```

**ProductList.js(then it takes each product and passes it to Product.js)**

```
import React from "react";
import Product from "./Product";
import { Container, Row, Col} from "react-bootstrap";

const chunk = (arr, chunkSize = 1, cache = []) => {
  const tmp = [...arr]
  if (chunkSize <= 0) return cache
  while (tmp.length) cache.push(tmp.splice(0, chunkSize))
  return cache
}

const ProductList = (props) => {
  const productsChunks = chunk(props.products, 3)
  
  const rows = productsChunks.map((productChunk, index) => {
        const productsCols = productChunk.map((product, index) => {
          return (
            <Col xs="auto" sm="auto" md="auto" lg="auto" key={product.id} style={{"paddingBottom":"20px"}}>
              <Product 
              key={product.id} 
              id={product.id}
              quantity={product.quantity} 
              price={product.price} 
              name={product.name} 
              description={product.description}
              manufacturer={product.manufacturer}
                {...props}
              />      
            </Col>
          );
        });
    return (
      <Row key={index} style={{"paddingBottom":"20px"}}>
       {productsCols}
      </Row>
            
  )});
    return (
    <Container>
      {rows}
    </Container>
  )
}

export default ProductList;
```

**Product.js(Here we show the each product)**

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Prompt, withRouter } from "react-router";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as productActions from "../redux/actions/productActions";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import toastr from "toastr";
import EditProduct from './EditProduct'
import {MdDelete,MdVisibility,MdCreate} from 'react-icons/md'


const Product = (props) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleClose     = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow      = () => setShow(true);
  
  const isLoggedIn = props.loggedIn
  const checkUser = (e) => {
      if (!isLoggedIn) {
        e.preventDefault();
        toastr.options = { positionClass: "toast-top-full-width",hideDuration: 300,timeOut: 2000,};
        toastr.clear();
        setTimeout(() => toastr.warning("Login to view details"), 0);
      }
  };

  const deleteProduct = () => {
    props.actions.deleteProduct(props.id)
  };
  //<Link to={'/ProductDetail/'+props.id}  >

  const product = {
    id :props.id,name:props.name,quantity:props.quantity,description:props.description,manufacturer:props.manufacturer,price:props.price
  }

  return (
    <>
    <Card style={{ width: "18rem", "borderRadius":"30px","border":"3px solid" }}>
      {isLoggedIn && (
        <Prompt when={isLoggedIn}
          message={(location) => location.pathname.includes("/ProductDetail/") ? `Are you sure you want to view the details ?` : true }
        />
      )}
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title style={{"fontSize":"30px","fontWeight":"bold","display":"flex", "justifyContent":"center"}}> {props.name} </Card.Title>
        {props.data.quantity && ( <Card.Text> Quantity : {props.quantity} </Card.Text> )}
        {props.data.manufacturer && <Card.Text> Manufacturer : {props.manufacturer}</Card.Text>}
        {props.data.price && <Card.Text>$ {props.price}</Card.Text>}

        <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-around" }}>
          

          <Link
          to={{
            pathname: `/ProductDetail/${props.id}`,
            productName: {
              id: props.id,
              name: props.name,
              price: props.price,
              quantity: props.quantity,
              description: props.description,
              manufacturer: props.manufacturer,
            },
          }}
        >
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={(event) => checkUser(event)} style={{ "fontWeight":"bold" }} > 
                {!isLoggedIn && <span style={{"paddingRight":"5px"}}>View</span> }
                {!isLoggedIn && <MdVisibility color="black"/> }
                {isLoggedIn && <MdVisibility/>}
            </Button>
          </Link>
          {isLoggedIn &&   <Button variant="success" style={{"fontWeight":"bold"  }} onClick={() => handleShow()} ><MdCreate/></Button> }    
          {isLoggedIn &&     <Button variant="danger" style={{"fontWeight":"bold"  }} onClick={() => deleteProduct()} ><MdDelete/> </Button>}
             
        </div>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
    <EditProduct show={show} handleClose={handleClose} actions={props.actions} product={product}/>
    </>
  );
};
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    products: state.products,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(productActions, dispatch),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(Product));
```

**ProductDetail.js(When clicked on View, it goes to this page to view details of the product)**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'
import {Button, Card} from 'react-bootstrap'


const ProductDetail=(props)=>{
    console.log(props)
    const style={"display":"flex", "justifyContent":"center","alignItems":"center"}
    return(
            <div style={style}>
                <Card style={{ width: "18rem","borderRadius":"30px" }}>
                    <Card.Body style={{style}}>
                        <Card.Title style={{"fontSize":"30px","fontWeight":"bold","display":"flex", "justifyContent":"center"}}> {props.location.productName.name} </Card.Title>
                        <Card.Text><strong>Quantity    :</strong>{props.location.productName.quantity}</Card.Text>
                        <Card.Text><strong>Price       :</strong>{props.location.productName.price}</Card.Text>
                        <Card.Text><strong>Manufacturer:</strong>{props.location.productName.manufacturer}</Card.Text>
                        <Card.Text><strong>Description :</strong>{props.location.productName.description}</Card.Text>
                        <div>
                        <Link to="/"><Button variant="primary" style={{ height: "6vh","fontWeight":"bold" }}>Back</Button></Link>
                        </div>
                    </Card.Body>
                </Card>
            </div>
        );
}
export default withRouter(ProductDetail);
```

**ProductReducer.js**

```
import initialState from "./initialState";
import * as actionTypes from "../actions/actionTypes";

export default function productReducer(state = initialState.products, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.INIT:
      return action.products;

    case actionTypes.ADD:
      return [...state, Object.assign({}, action.product)];

    case actionTypes.DELETE:
      return [...state.filter((product) => product.id !== action.id)];

    case actionTypes.UPDATE:
      return [
        ...state.filter((product) => product.id !== action.product.id),
        Object.assign({}, action.product),
      ];

    case actionTypes.VIEW:
      return [
        ...state[action.product.id],
        Object.assign({},action.product.view)
      ]

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**ProductActions.js**

```
import dataApi from "../../server/dataAPI";
import * as actionTypes from "../actions/actionTypes";

//======================LOADING A PRODUCT
export function loadProduct() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return dataApi
      .getAllProducts()
      .then((products) => {
        dispatch({ type: actionTypes.INIT, products });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  };
}
//==========================ADDING A PRODUCT
export function addProduct(product) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return dataApi
      .addProduct(product)
      .then((product) => {
        dispatch({ type: actionTypes.ADD, product });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  };
}

//==========================DELETE A PRODUCT
export function deleteProduct(id) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return dataApi
      .deleteProduct(id)
      .then((product) => {
        dispatch({ type: actionTypes.DELETE, id});
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  };
}

//==========================UPDATE A PRODUCT
export function updateProduct(product) {
    return function (dispatch) {
      return dataApi
        .updateProduct(product)
        .then((product) => {
          dispatch({ type: actionTypes.UPDATE, product });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          throw error;
        });
    };
  }

  //Increase View Count of product
  export function addView(product){
    return function (dispatch){
      return dataApi.addView(product)
      .then(product=>{
        dispatch({type:actionTypes.VIEW, product})
      })
    }
  }
```

**dataAPI.js(to add,delete,update to json server with axios)**

```
import axios from 'axios'

class dataAPI {
    static  getAllProducts() {
        return axios.get('http://localhost:4000/products?_sort=id&_order=asc').then(response=>response.data);
    }

    static addProduct(product) {
        return axios.post('http://localhost:4000/products',product).then(response=>response.data);
    }
    
    static updateProduct(product){
        return axios.patch('http://localhost:4000/products/'+product.id,product)
        .then(response=>response.data);
    }

    static deleteProduct(id){
        return axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/products/${id}`).then(response=>response.data);
    }

    static getAllUsers(){
        return axios.get('http://localhost:4000/users').then(response=>response.data);
    }

    static addUser(user) {
        return axios.post('http://localhost:4000/users',user).then(response=>response.data);
    }
}

export default dataAPI;
```

**db.json(the file that contains all the data)**

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Moto G5 Ultra",
      "quantity": 3,
      "price": 10000,
      "description": "Moto G5",
      "manufacturer": "Motorola",
      "views" : 0
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Racold Geyser",
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": 60000,
      "description": "Moto G5",
      "manufacturer": "Motorola",
      "views" : 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Lenovo G5",
      "quantity": 3,
      "price": 55000,
      "manufacturer": "Lenovo",
      "description": "A gaming laptop",
      "id": 3,
      "views" : 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Acer Swift ",
      "quantity": 5,
      "price": 35000,
      "manufacturer": "Acer",
      "description": "Business Laptop",
      "id": 4,
      "views" : 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Acer Nitro 7",
      "quantity": 4,
      "price": 75000,
      "manufacturer": "Acer",
      "description": "A gaming laptop",
      "id": 5,
      "views" : 0
    },
    "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "email": "vi@gmail.com",
      "password": "truth",
      "name": {
        "firstName": "Rick",
        "lastName": "Garner"
      },
      "location": "Canada",
      "mobile": "55643980"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "email": "t@t.com",
      "password": "123",
      "name": {
        "firstName": "Ram",
        "lastName": "Shankar"
      },
      "location": "Delhi",
      "mobile": "9895454860"
    },
    {
      "email": "e@e.com",
      "password": "123456789",
      "name": {
        "firstName": "RAGAV",
        "lastName": "Shant"
      },
      "location": "Karnataka",
      "mobile": "1234567891",
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "email": "k@k.com",
      "password": "123456789",
      "name": {
        "firstName": "sd",
        "lastName": "dv"
      },
      "location": "dfv",
      "mobile": "12345678231",
      "id": 4
    }
    
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So what i did was I added a useEffect() to my ProductDetail.js file and fired the Action from there.**

ProductDetail.js

```
import React,{useEffect} from 'react';
import { Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'
import {Button, Card} from 'react-bootstrap'
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as productActions from "../redux/actions/productActions";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";


const ProductDetail=(props)=>{
    useEffect(() => {

        console.log("PROPIES ",props.location.productName.id+" "+props.location.productName.views)
        props.actions.addView(props.location.productName.id,props.location.productName.views)
    
    },[props.actions,props.location.productName.id,props.location.productName.views])
    const style={"display":"flex", "justifyContent":"center","alignItems":"center","minHeight":"100vh"}
    return(
            <div style={style}>
                <Card style={{ width: "18rem","borderRadius":"30px" }} >
                    <Card.Body style={{style}}>
                        <Card.Title style={{"fontSize":"30px","fontWeight":"bold","display":"flex", "justifyContent":"center"}}> {props.location.productName.name} </Card.Title>
                        <Card.Text><strong>Quantity    :</strong>{props.location.productName.quantity}</Card.Text>
                        <Card.Text><strong>Price       :</strong>{props.location.productName.price}</Card.Text>
                        <Card.Text><strong>Manufacturer:</strong>{props.location.productName.manufacturer}</Card.Text>
                        <Card.Text><strong>Description :</strong>{props.location.productName.description}</Card.Text>
                        <div>
                        <Link to="/"><Button variant="primary" style={{ height: "6vh","fontWeight":"bold" }}>Back</Button></Link>
                        </div>
                    </Card.Body>
                </Card>
            </div>
        );
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
      products: state.products,
    };
  }
  
  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
      actions: bindActionCreators(productActions, dispatch),
    };
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(ProductDetail));
```

**It then fires this action**

```
//Increase View Count of product
  export function addView(id,count){
    console.log("func called")
    return function (dispatch){
      console.log("api to be called")
      return dataApi.addView(id,count)
      .then((product)=>{
        console.log("dispatched")
        dispatch({type:actionTypes.VIEW, id: product.id})
      })
    }
  }
```

**So it updates the view on the server first and then in the reducer state**

dataAPI.js

```
static addView(id,count){
      return axios.patch('http://localhost:4000/products/'+id,{views:count+1})
        .then(response=>response.data);
    }
```

productReducer.js

```
import initialState from "./initialState";
import * as actionTypes from "../actions/actionTypes";

export default function productReducer(state = initialState.products, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.INIT:
      return action.products;

    case actionTypes.ADD:
      return [...state, Object.assign({}, action.product)];

    case actionTypes.DELETE:
      return [...state.filter((product) => product.id !== action.id)];

    case actionTypes.UPDATE:
      return [
        ...state.filter((product) => product.id !== action.product.id),
        Object.assign({}, action.product),
      ].sort( (a,b)=>(a.id>b.id)?1:-1 );

    case actionTypes.VIEW:
      let prod = [...state][action.id-1];
      prod.views++;
      //eslint-disable-next-line
      let addView =()=>( [
           ...state.filter(product => product.id !== action.id),
           Object.assign({}, prod)
         ])
      return state;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**I had to write the ActionType.VIEW case in switch like this**

```
case actionTypes.VIEW:
      let prod = [...state][action.id-1];
      prod.views++;
      //eslint-disable-next-line
      let addView =()=>( [
           ...state.filter(product => product.id !== action.id),
           Object.assign({}, prod)
         ])
      return state;
```

**I had to put the state modification part inside a function called addView(), otherwise I saw that the function was repeatedly getting called infinitly. I'd appreciate it is someone could help me with a around that**

Answer (score 1):

You may want to dispatch update products action in useEffect inside `ProductDetail.jsx` page.

```
useEffect(() => {
  updateProduct({
    ...props.location.productName,
    views: props.location.productName + 1,
  });
}, []);
```

Of course you will also need to pass `views` from `Product.jsx`.
This will increase views every time user opens/refreshes page.

EDIT:

If you want to have separate API endpoint for incrementing view count, you can implement its increment logic on server side. In that case, it won't change anything in current reducer file `ProductReducer.js`.
But I think there is no need for it. You can use updateProduct API , just for this reason. No need to change reducer in this case also.

EDIT 2:

If `addView` API is returning product id and incremented view, then you you can write reducer as -

```
case actionTypes.VIEW:
  return [
    ...state.map((product) => {
      if (product.id === action.product.id) {
        product.views = action.product.views;
      }
      return product;
    })
  ]
```

Comment: I'd like to know how to write the case in switch for reducer.

Comment: case actionTypes.VIEW:
      return [
        ...state[action.product.id],
        Object.assign({},state.views+1)
      ]

Comment: Do we do it like this ?

Comment: How do I make change to a single property in an object in the state ?

Comment: The thing is.... The API part is perfectly working. But the problem I'm facing is with the state in product reducer. Like.....how should use the spread operator (...state), and then find the object with the id, and increment it's view count ?

Comment: What does `dataApi.addView` return? Is it returning updated Product with incremented View? If it is so, then it will be same as UPDATE reducer, right?

Comment: No. For update reducer, I'm sending the whole product into the patch method. But in add veiw of dataAPI, I'm just accepting the id and previous count, then doing something like axios.patch('url'+id,{views: count +1}).then(resp=>resp.data)